# Ruby FTP nlst returns file name twice

Tags: ruby, ftp

When using nlst on an exact match for a filename I'm seeing some rather strange results (below). Can anyone help explain this?

Wild Card - Good

```
ftp.nlst('*ItemPrice.xml')
# => ["/Output/ItemPrice.xml"]
```

Wild Card - Good

```
ftp.nlst('*.xml')
# => ["/Output/ItemAvailability.xml", "/Output/ItemPrice.xml", "/Output/ItemUpsert.xml"]
```

Exact Match - Bad

```
ftp.nlst('ItemPrice.xml')
# => ["/Output/ItemPrice.xml/Output/ItemPrice.xml"]
```

Comment: What FTP library are you using? What happens if you try these commands using an interactive FTP client? Also, sheesh, it's 2016 and FTP is still a thing?

Comment: Just using plain old Net::FTP (http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/FTP) on this one.

Comment: Set `debug_mode` to true and show us the output.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Same nlst with debug_mode set to true -- > ftp.nlst(ftp_filename) put: TYPE A get: 200 Type set to A. put: PASV get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XX,XX,XX,251,76) put: NLST ItemPrice.xml get: 150 ASCII data connection for /Output/ItemPrice.xml (XX.XXX.XX.142,57992). get: 226 ASCII transfer complete. put: TYPE I get: 200 Type set to I. => ["/Output/ItemPrice.xml/Output/ItemPrice.xml"]

Comment: Please edit this information into your question in a readable format.

Comment: And also, include the same for `ftp.nlst('*ItemPrice.xml')`.